# SQL Server - JOIN isn't using the optimal order in Entity Framework's generated query

Tags: sql-server, performance, entity-framework, database-performance

I'm using Entity Framework to execute a rather complex query on my DB. The query consists of the `.Union()` of a couple of other `IQueryables`.

In an attempt to optimize said query, I've broken down the different sub-queries and tested them individually to measure performance and found out that one of them (let's call it `joinRes`) is quite slower than the others.

`joinRes` is a join between two (filtered) tables where one of the tables has a huge amount of records, while the other only has a couple of them.

```
var smallDataSet = RepositoryForSmallDataSet.Where(smDs => ... );

var joinRes = smallDataSet.Join(largeDataSet, 
                                 smDs => smDs.SomeID, 
                                 bigDs => bigDs.SomeID, 
                                 (smDs, bigDs) => bigDs)
                          .OrderByDescending(bigDs => bigDs.SomeDate);

// ... IQueryable joinRes will be used in some .Union() operations with other IQueryables into a largeQuery IQueryable...

var result = largeQuery.Take(10).ToList();
```

Looking at the actual execution plan in SQL Server, I can see that the `Nested Loops` step in the `joinRes` subquery isn't choosing the optimal order (`smallDataSet` first then `largeDataSet`). If I add a `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` hint to the generated SQL, the sub query is much faster.

[image: SQL Server Execution Plan join]

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to add that hint via Entity Framework, and simply moving the complex query (remember that `joinRes` is part of a large complex one) onto a stored procedure would be a major hassle (it's a heavily dynamically generated query, and it would likely require a lot of dynamic SQL).

Any suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

### EDIT:

Evaldas Buinauskas put me on the right track with his answer. [Poor performance was caused by `Key Lookup`](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/how-to-eliminate-key-lookups-in-sql-server-2008/) as well as a bunch of other JOINS caused by a [TPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618293.aspx) inheritance mechanism (not mentioned in this question). Fixed the indexes (based on SQL Server's execution plan) and refactored inheritance to use a [TPH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx) approach instead.

Comment: Seems you should update statistics on these tables.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko, I did try a `EXEC sp_updatestats`. As well as rebuilding the Indexes. No luck.

Comment: What is the actual query? Why do you assume that the order isn't optimal? Anyway, EF/LINQ aren't a replacement for SQL. If you have to do joins with LINQ, you are using the wrong entities/relations. There should be a *relation* from the parent entity to the child entity. *Entity names* with the word "dataset" are a very strong smell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your indexes right? Because `Key Lookup` indicates that your index doesn't cover join condition or it's outputting columns that are not included in your index.

It's adviced to eliminate them (lookups). This is a [very detailed article](https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/06/09/how-to-eliminate-key-lookups-in-sql-server-2008) explaining how to do it.

> Key lookups occur when you have an index seek against a table, but
>   your query requires additional columns that are not in that index.
>   This causes SQL Server to have to go back and retrieve those extra
>   columns.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into that and get back to you.

Comment: Well spotted. It wasn't the only reason, but your input was key in improving performance. Thanks.